# How to edit the calendar control in a gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms, calendar-control

I tried to update the data in edit mode of gridview.

It does not send correctly with my actual code. I tried to make it a templateField in HTML and it does not work. At this moment,the program break when I modify the date in the edit mode of gridview.
This is put in Page_Load.In the condition to sort the grid, the grid is binding.

```
     if (ViewState["sorting"] == null)
    {

        String myquery = "Select * from Venituri";
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = myquery,
            Connection = sqlCon
        };
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
        {
            SelectCommand = cmd
        };
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridViewIncomes.DataSource = ds;
        GridViewIncomes.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
        GridViewIncomes.DataBind(); //here is a break when I was modified with the suggest code
    }




protected void GridViewIncomes_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(CS);
    int index = GridViewIncomes.EditIndex;
    GridViewRow row = GridViewIncomes.Rows[index];
    int VenitId = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewIncomes.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    string Denumire = ((TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text.ToString().Trim();
    var MyDateInsCalendar = GridViewIncomes.Rows[GridViewIncomes.EditIndex].FindControl("Data") as Calendar;
    MyDateInsCalendar.Visible = false;
    string Suma = ((TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text.ToString().Trim();
    string Descriere = ((TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0]).Text.ToString().Trim();
    string sql = "UPDATE Venituri SET Denumire='" + Denumire + "',Data='" + MyDateInsCalendar + "',Suma='" + Suma + "',Descriere='" + Descriere + "' WHERE VenitId=" + VenitId + "";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCon);
    sqlCon.Open();
    int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCon.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {

        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Actualizat cu succes!";
    }
    GridViewIncomes.EditIndex = -1;
    lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";

}
```

`

`.aspx
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="Data" DataField="Data" />`

To edit the date into gridview and update in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyDateInsCalendar` variable is an objcect (Calendar). Use one of the properties of this variable in your SQL statement.

for example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>                
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
    tmp.Add("a");
    GridView1.DataSource = tmp;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Calendar cal = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Calendar1") as Calendar;
    string tmp = cal.SelectedDate.ToString();
    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: It's not working. The error is: reference to an null object. I think the problem is at this line:   var MyDateInsCalendar = GridViewIncomes.Rows[GridViewIncomes.EditIndex].FindControl("Data") as Calendar;

Comment: I hope this example will be help for you

Comment: I edit my code above. I can not use totally your suggestion because I had a SQLData Source and can not bind twice. I use only the part with calendar. I got the following error: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.'

Comment: Your MyDateInsCalendar variable is an object (Calendar). Use one of the properties of this variable in your SQL statement. for example: MyDateInsCalendar.SelectedDate.To.String()

Comment: From your code I copy the lines in Grid_Updating; I use in SQL statement 'tmp', is this the same thing,right?

Comment: I found a solutin within the code does not break.    'DateTime del = DateTime.ParseExact(((TextBox)GridViewIncomes.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("tbDataEdit")).Text,"dd/mm/yyyy",null);' but throws an exception: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
del={1 Jan 0001 00:00:00}.